# Deluge daemon connection?

Tags: connection, bittorrent, localhost, deluge

My deluge-console is suddenly giving me this error

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:58846 with reason: Connection refused
```

why is this error.I have done nothing and the GUI deluge runs fine.Its the problem in console only? Why localhost is refusing connection and how do I connect to daemon? I have tried the command

```
connect 127.0.0.1 58846
```

but it doesnt seems to work.

Answer (score 10):

The most probable reason is that you are not running the daemon. To start the daemon use 
`deluged`

Then try `deluge-console`

Answer (score 4):

The most common reason is because you are running deluged as a different user to the one you are running deluge-console with.

From the Deluge [wiki](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient#EnableRemoteConnection):

> If you are running deluged under another user you will need to
>   temporarily login as that user to enable deluge-console to access that
>   daemon's config:
>
> ```
> su --shell /bin/bash --login deluge
> ```

Comment: I can't make this work. Do I need some config on deluge user? I added him a password but still not working. I find http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient#AccessingdelugedservicewithlocalUIClient here something about a mysthic auth file but I can't find it on my installation.

Comment: This is for the local user `deluge` to connect to a running daemon so uses  the localhost password that is autogenerated. For reference the `auth` file is in `~/.config` by default, see the Deluge wiki pages for details. Ask in Deluge forums if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your actual user name is "pi" (or change it with the correct one), try this:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

then, at the end of the file, between "fi" and "exit 0" add the following lines:

```
# Start Deluge on boot:
```

```
sudo -u pi /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/deluged
```

```
# Start Deluge-Web on boot:
```

```
sudo -u pi /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/deluge-web
```

Just copy and paste all but if you don't use the web interface cut off the last two lines above here;
after this, do: ctrl-x , reply "y" , push "return button" and then type "sudo reboot".
Everithing should be fixed after restart.